# How to resolve bash commands on sqlplus "command not found" error

Tags: oracle

i wanted to get in to sqlplus to run some sqlfiles,i ran these lines and when i give sqlplus to enetr in to sqlplus, i will get err, 
i have not downloded and installed anythng otherthan running these commands, so could some one plese help me??

```
[root@localhost instances]# export 
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
[root@localhost instances]#  export ORACLE_SID=XE
[root@localhost instances]# export NLS_LANG=$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh
[root@localhost instances]# export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
[root@localhost instances]# sqlplus

-bash: sqlplus: command not found
```

Comment: If you are on a 64-bit machine, try `sqlplus64`

Comment: "i have not downloded and installed anythng" - sqlplus doesn't ship with the OS, you have to download and install at a minimum, an Oracle client, or even better just get SQLcl

Comment: thanks all for your fast response,
But do i need to download oracle 11g/oracle instant client etc? before doing the above 4 commands?

Comment: what is the password for sqlplus if am entering fresh ,
i have given username as: SYSTEM,

Password:??????

Comment: do i need to download and install oracle 11gXE and give the login details(which are given at the time of installing oracle 11gXE ) to login to sqlplus??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`export NLS_LANG=$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh` seems to be wrong. `NLS_LANG` is a string of format `language_territory.charset`, see [NLS_LANG FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html)

In case `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh` provides NLS_LANG value dynamically then it should be

```
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
```

Comment: ok thank you,
 what is the password for sqlplus if am entering fresh